# $_Post not retrieving data while $_Get is

Tags: php

I am new to Php so i basically dont know much 
just started studying from a book php and mysql 
doing the same as the book said but my code doesnt fetch the data if i use Post method but does work if i use Get method. the book has used post so kind of confused here :/
this is the html part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="processorder.php" method="POST">
    <table border="0">
        <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
            <td width="150">Item</td>
            <td width="15">Quantity</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tires</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="tireqty" size="3"
                                      maxlength="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Oil</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="oilqty" size="3"
                                      maxlength="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Spark Plugs</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="sparkqty" size="3"
                                      maxlength="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT ORDER" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the php code is this

```
<html>
<?php
// create short variable names
$tireqty = $_POST['tireqty'];
$oilqty = $_POST['oilqty'];
$sparkqty = $_POST['sparkqty'];
?>
<head>
    <title>Bob’s Auto Parts - Order Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bob’s Auto Parts</h1>
<h2>Order Results</h2>

<?php
echo "<p>Order processed at " .date('H:i, jS F Y')."</p>";
echo '<p>Your order is as follows: </p>';
echo $tireqty.' tires<br />';
echo $oilqty.' bottles of oil<br />';
echo $sparkqty.' spark plugs<br />';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

If i use the _GEt method the values of this variables are shown but with post method nothing is retrieved.

Comment: you can use$_REQUEST insted of $_POST

Comment: Are you reading from `$_POST` only when "submitting" the form?

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST);` and checkout the result

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPMDVwk0mhG6pIMQQ9-8eEG636S-MoqWmc — I can't reproduce the problem. Best guess is that you are using a cached version of the HTML where the form still says GET.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: tested your code and is working fine. Clear browser cache and check again..

Comment: Hi @Daniyal : Use this line before `<html>` => Write `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">` At the beginning of two pages and check whether working or not.

Comment: @basheerAhmed print_r($_post) gave this output Array ( )

Comment: @SAMEERK I AM USING PHPSTORM CAN YOU tell me on which did you run it on ?

Comment: If the above DOCTYPE doesn't work. Then use this `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/loose.dtd">` Let me know what happened.

Comment: @NanaPartykar THE FIrst one didnt work and the second URI is not registered

Comment: Ok. Is PHPSTORM related to IIS. Just asking ?

Comment: I'm damn sure about configuration issue. Code is fine.

Comment: @NanaPartykar i do remember configuring iis for phpstorm

Comment: Ok. Then, There is issue. Wait. I'm giving you link. Just follow it step by step.

Comment: @DaniyalAhmed : Go Ahead Man. http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/verbs

Comment: @NanaPartykar PhpStorm is an IDE on Mac OS X.

Comment: Hi Mr @Barmar : See I don't have any idea about it. I asked him about IIS related thing. He said *i do remember configuring iis for phpstorm*. So, just for helping I gave this link to him.

Comment: @NanaPartykar its already turned on 
but just one question 
which verb should i write in deny verb ?

Comment: Hi @DaniyalAhmed : I don't have much idea about this. But, they have written TRACE. So, you can try TRACE. But not sure. *Sorry.*

Comment: @NanaPartykar i just have my final project in a month and i've been on this since a week :/
the trace doesnt work though :/
Thanks though :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Are you sure post not working, Please check post method contains data or not by using.

> var_dump($_POST); and     var_dump($_REQUEST);

if you don't found anything in post then it will be in request if it is then your request is submitting by get method.

if it display an array with array entered in post then your post method is working and problem is with your file and your file was unable to open due to some security problem/incorrect path or may be due to file permission. So check and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you used `form` attribute `method` is `POST` definitely you will get the data using `$_POST` in the php file might be there is caching issue or instead of `$_POST` you can use it `$_REQUEST` but i would suggest you clear your cache first then try again with `$_POST`

Also I do not think this is a code issue, rather it is a configuration issue with either apache or php. and you should only go with `$_POST` is more secure!

Thanks

Comment: THE request and get both methods are working 
even clearing the cache didnt help for post

Comment: Have you check "post_max_size" in the php.ini file ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors while use $_POST ?

Comment: Also try to exclude all js if you're using on the page.

Comment: NO JS
and no error 
just null value

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Please put these above lines there and check any error showing and let me know

Comment: 'Order processed at 16:07, 24th December 2015

Your order is as follows:

tires
bottles of oil
spark plugs
Items ordered: 0
Subtotal: $0.00
Total including tax: $0.00

The output 
no errors

Comment: Unfortunately, i think Apache or PHP was not installed properly. take your projects and DB backup and uninstall and install it again! Good luck if you if you agree with answer make it right answer. thanks

Comment: i have php storms 
php was already installed and apache too

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['tireqty'])) {
        $tireqty = $_POST['tireqty'];
        $oilqty = $_POST['oilqty'];
        $sparkqty = $_POST['sparkqty'];
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please do not post code without any supporting text.  Explain what this snippet does and how it would help the OP solve their problem.  Help others to understand.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.